# API Error Code: 100 getting Facebook Share on Pages

Tags: jquery, feed, fb.ui

During fb share on pages using **Fb.ui** is throwing error.
I am using the following code

```
FB.ui(
            {
                method: 'feed',
                display: "popup",
                picture: picture,
                name: 'offer name',
                link: link,
                caption: 'provider name',
                description: 'some message',
                to: page_id,
                from: page_id
            },
            function(response) {
                if (response && !response.error_code) {

                   alert('Successfully posted on Facebook');
                }else{

                   alert('Error while posting.');
                }
            });
```

During sending feed I am **getting this error dialog from facebook**

[image]

I have **permitted following categories** on app page (status & review)

[image]

What is the issue? Would you please provide me with a solution?